# Create MySql User with Store Procedure (Server Mode)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have successfully create a user name = 'root' and host = '127 .0.0.1 ', use the mysql command (client mode) as follow:

```
sql = String.Format("CREATE USER '{0}'@'{1}' IDENTIFIED BY '{2}'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO '{0}'@'{1}' IDENTIFIED BY '{2}' WITH GRANT OPTION;", userName, serverHost, userPassword)
```

When the script above I change it to store procedure (server mode) as below, I found the error as follows: (Error 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual That corresponds to Yout MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'pass' at line 1)

```
ScriptExec(String.Format("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mySchema.SP_CreateUser $$" +
                         "CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE {0}.SP_CreateUser(IN userName VARCHAR(250), IN serverHost VARCHAR(250), IN userPassword VARCHAR(250)) " +
                         "BEGIN " +
                         "SET @buf = CONCAT('CREATE USER ',userName,'@',serverHost,' IDENTIFIED BY ',userPassword); PREPARE stmt FROM @buf; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;" +
                         "SET @buf1 = CONCAT('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO ',userName,'@',serverHost,' IDENTIFIED BY ',userPassword,' WITH GRANT OPTION'); PREPARE stmt1 FROM @buf1; EXECUTE stmt1; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;" +
                         "END $$"))

Public Function ScriptExec(ByVal sql As String) As Boolean
    Dim stsResult As Boolean = Nothing
    Dim has As Integer = Nothing
    Dim script As New MySqlScript(objCon, sql)
    script.Delimiter = "$$"
    Try
        has = script.Execute()
        If has > 0 Then stsResult = True
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error occurred in ScriptExec Function" & vbCrLf & ex.Number & " – " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        script.Delimiter = ";"
    End Try
    Return stsResult
End Function
```

Is there a solution to my problem above?

Thanks & Best Regards,

Yudha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you missing a

```
DELIMITER $$
```

statement at the beginning of your SQL code? Without it, the engine won't know how to interpret the `$$`.

Comment: I used  script.Delimiter = "$$" in ScriptExec function. Possibility of error occurs because the format CREATE USER username@serverHost, should CREATE USER 'username'@'serverHost'. There is an opening and closing quotes there. How do I use an opening and closing quotes in CONCAT, because i'm used variable for userName and serverHost?

Comment: True, what I expected. I change my username,'@',userPassword become QUOTE(username),'@',QUOTE(serverHost) and 'IDENTIFIED BY',userPassword) to 'IDENTIFIED BY', QUOTE(userPassword)). All is now functioning normally. Thank you for helping me. //Yudha